# makeing a variable act like a number in python

Tags: python, variables

i was wondering, in python how could i have variable, such as a word act like a number to create a system of points that's writen to a text file on my computer.i will paste code

```
def pointsystem():
import easygui
points = open ('totalpoints.txt', 'r')
readpts = points.readline()
points.close
pointsinput = easygui.enterbox("enter paretal password")
if pointsinput == 'testpass':
    pointsadd = easygui.enterbox("enter points")
    pointsedit = open ('totalpoints.txt', 'a')
    pointsedit.write(readpts + pointsadd)
    pointsedit.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that `readpts = int(readpts)` and `pointsadd = int(pointsadd)` would do the trick, converting those strings to numbers. Then change them back with `str(readpts + pointsadd)` when it's time to write.

EDIT based on comments: You can't actually store a number inside a file as an integer type (or if you can, it's more trouble than it's worth). If you want to replace a number inside a file with a totally new number, instead of continually adding new numbers, use `pointsedit = open ('totalpoints.txt', 'w')` instead of `pointsedit = open ('totalpoints.txt', 'a')`. This will erase the original contents of the file and replace it with the new contents (the new number of points) instead of just adding more and more numbers. But it has to be read in as a string, and written out as a string. It's really so much easier.

```
def pointsystem():
  import easygui
  points = open ('totalpoints.txt', 'r')
  readpts = points.readline()
  points.close()
  readpts = int(readpts)
  pointsinput = easygui.enterbox("enter paretal password")
  if pointsinput == 'testpass':
    pointsadd = easygui.enterbox("enter points")
    pointsadd = int(pointsadd)
    pointsedit = open ('totalpoints.txt', 'w')
    pointsedit.write(str(readpts + pointsadd))
    pointsedit.close()
```

Comment: erm, i kinda need to write them to the file as numbers, but when i try that i get this typeerror: unsuported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to write raw numbers to a file in Python, and it's definitely more trouble than it's worth. As for that error, it sounds like you're only converting one of those two variables to an integer. Why do they need to be written as numbers and not strings?

Comment: becasue if its not coverted when i try to add 10 points for example i get 010and then if i added 20 more i would get 01020

Comment: Wait, how are you trying to do this? The use case I'm now imagining is that you have "10" in your file, then you add in "20" and the result is that "30" is the only thing in your points file. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes, and when i tried the code above i get a valueerror with line 6, invalaid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Well for the first thing: that's really not something you should be doing in a file. For the second thing, what are the contents of your points file?

Comment: the contents are the number zero, its just a .txt file